# Can I draw Hasse or lattice diagrams using Vaucanson-G package?

Tags: diagrams

I am drawing automaton diagrams using Vaucanson-G package. Can I draw Hasse( or Lattice) diagrams using the same package?
S.G. Sekaran

Comment: Questions seeking formatting help ("**how to do this in LaTeX?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).